# Floating left: long texts makes it fall apart

Tags: html, css

I want this result:

```
LEFT THING, not fixed    here comes a text, which is 100% widthed in this "column"
width (content itself    but my problem is, when its too long, this column goes under the
determines that)         left column, so not left floated. I also want this text go and
                         go under and under, but normally, THIS LINE would continue under
                         the left column, which I dont want to. Its like table element
                         but its still considered bad for this situations :/
```

the DIV construction:

```
<div style="float: left">LEFT THING</div>
<div style="float: left">here comes a text, which...</div>
```

how to solve it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Floated elements with `width: auto` are sized using the [shrink-to-fit algorithm](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#shrink-to-fit-float). That is, they attempt to grow as much as their content wants.

To avoid this, you should limit the width, e.g. by setting an explicit `width` or an upper bound with `max-width`.

Then, to make the following block grow to fill the remaining space, you should let it have the default `float: none` and`width: auto`, and establish a Block Formatting Context (BFC) to prevent it from overlapping the float.

```css
.wrapper, .main {
  overflow: hidden; /* Establish Block Formatting Context */
}
.left {
  float: left;
  max-width: 30%; /* Prevent it from growing too wide */
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="left">...</div>
  <div class="main">...</div>
</div>
```

```css
.wrapper, .main{
  overflow: hidden; /* Establish Block Formatting Context */
  text-align: justify;
}
.left {
  float: left;
  max-width: 30%; /* Prevent it from growing too wide */
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
.main {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="left">LEFT THING LEFT THING LEFT THING LEFT THING</div>
  <div class="main">here comes a text, which... here comes a text, which... here comes a text, which... here comes a text, which... here comes a text, which... here comes a text, which... here comes a text, which... here comes a text, which... here comes a text, which... here comes a text, which... here comes a text, which... here comes a text, which... here comes a text, which... here comes a text, which... here comes a text, which...</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

add width to your elements to be able to float them, then will have the required result.

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/q8SfB/1

Comment: He does not want to fix the width of either column.

Comment: @adu you can't float elements without known width.